# How to convert excel formula to dax as measurement in powerbi or M (power query)

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, measurement

I have a formula from excel, what I want to transform into DAX, i need it as a measurement for powerbi or power query as M

The formula from excel is:

```
=IF(IF(G2=1;COUNTIFS(O:O;O2;C:C;">="&C2;C:C;"<="&C2+1;M:M;">"&M2);0)>0;1;0)
```

where:
G is column abandon,
O is column customer,
C is column date,
M is column DateTime

this is a double if where the first is:

```
IF(G2=1;COUNTIFS(O:O;O2;C:C;">="&C2;C:C;"<="&C2+1;M:M;">"&M2);0)
```

and this is used as condition for the second if what is:

```
=IF("if1">0;1;0)
```

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing sample data and desired output, and thus is hard to understand and answer.

Sample below in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"C", type date}, {"M", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","dM",(x)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [O]=x[O] and [C]>=x[C] and [C]<=Date.AddDays(x[C],1) and [M]>x[M]) )),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each try if [G]=1 and [dM]>0 then 1 else 0 otherwise null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"dM"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

| G | O | C | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 12:30:00 |
| 1 | bbb | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 13:30:00 |
| 1 | aaa | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 14:30:00 |
| 0 | bbb | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 12:30:00 |
| 0 | aaa | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 13:30:00 |
| 0 | bbb | 01/10/2020 | 01/10/20 14:30:00 |
| 1 | aaa | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 12:30:00 |
| 1 | bbb | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 13:30:00 |
| 1 | aaa | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 14:30:00 |
| 0 | bbb | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 12:30:00 |
| 0 | aaa | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 13:30:00 |
| 0 | bbb | 01/11/2020 | 01/11/20 14:30:00 |

and get

[image]